# Given a path to a jar file on disk, at what point is its URI defined as jar:file:? Is this something I have to do myself?

Tags: java, jar, uri

I have a jar file on disk that I want to connect to as a `JarURLConnection`. The problem is that when I open it as a `File` it is of URI type `file:`.

```
System.out.println(new java.io.File("test.jar").toURI().toURL());
```

Output:

```
file:/C:/path/test.jar
```

If I have only a string path to the file on disk, do I need to identify the URI type myself or is there a way to derive it at some point in processing?

I was planning to test whether it was a jar file like this:

```
URLConnection urlc = new java.io.File(jarPath).toURI().toURL().openConnection();

if (!(urlc instanceof JarURLConnection))
   throw new IOException("File type is not a jar");
```

But the URI isn't a `jar:file:` at this point.

How do I set the URI type of a File? And is this the correct procedure when opening a connection to a jar file?

Comment: As pointed out below, you don't "set the URI type of a File". You take a URL and then prepend `file:` to it. The original URL does not have to point to a file, you just happen to want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html) of `JarURLConnection`:

```
 URL url = new URL("jar:file:/home/duke/duke.jar!/");
 JarURLConnection jarConnection = (JarURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

[image]